# Multiple calculations and targeted output in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

As a learning exercise and to also create a simple, but helpful little tool (for me), I am trying to create a web-based form that will take price and quantity data for multiple items and then produce a "per unit cost" (price divided by item quantity).  Based on that info, I then want further calculations to provide a final cost based on the cost totals for several unit costs of those items.  I have this simple little tool built in an Excel spreadsheet, but I want it in web format also.

I am into shooting as a hobby and I reload my own ammo.  This tool takes the bulk price/quantity for four items; bullets, powder, primers, and brass cases, gives the per unit cost and then will tell me the cost per round of ammo (first iteration is the most expensive as new brass casing costs are included), then subsequent loadings (selectable number) is calculated using only bullet, powder, and primer cost since the brass can be reloaded multiple times.

I have the initial start with the html displaying two lines of user input, first line is: bullet, price, quantity, unit.  Second line is Powder, price, quantity, unit.  The form input is formatted using css grid.

I have a script that works to do the calculations for the first line for the bullet, but I don't know how to get it to reiterate and then calculate and output the powder data.  I've read numerous sites concerning form calculations and most if it went right over my head.  Some help with this would be appreciated.

```js
(function () {
    function calculateUnitCost(bprice, bquantity) {
        bprice = parseFloat(bprice);
        bquantity = parseFloat(bquantity);
        bcost = (bprice*0.06+bprice)/bquantity;
        return bcost.toPrecision(2);
    
    }

    var unitCost = document.getElementById("unitCost");
    if (unitCost) {
        unitCost.onsubmit = function () {
            this.bunit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.bprice.value, this.bquantity.value);          
            return false;
        };

    }
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Unit Cost Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contain">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Load Cost Calculator</h3>

      <form id="unitCost" action="">
        <p>
          <label for="bullet">Bullet </label>
          <input id="bullet" name="bullet" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="bprice">Price </label>
          <input id="bprice" name="bprice" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="bquantity">Quantity </label>
          <input id="bquantity" name="bquantity" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="bunit">Unit Cost </label>
          <input id="bunit" name="bunit" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="powder">Powder </label>
          <input id="powder" name="powder" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="pprice">Price </label>
          <input id="pprice" name="pprice" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="pquantity">Quantity </label>
          <input id="pquantity" name="pquantity" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="punit">Unit Cost </label>
          <input id="punit" name="punit" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="subm"></label>
          <input type="submit" value="Calculate Per Unit Cost" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="rest"></label>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ok, the suggestion by Ayaz does work, sort of.  I swear I tried that before and it did not.  I even still have the old copy where I tried it, I just went back and it doesn't work, but for some reason editing the current working copy, with the exact same code, it works.  Sigh, anyway...I've also figured out the code to get and calculate the powder data and it too works.

The formula for the powder unit cost is different than for bullets.  Bullets are sold in quantity counts, 50, 100, etc.  Powder is sold by weight, typically in 1lb or 8lb containers.  However, for calculating per cartridge loading costs there is a second weight unit used, "grains."  There are 7000 grains to 1lb.  So, the formula I am trying to use for powder is

```
(pprice*0.06+pprice)/(pquantity*7000)
```

The 0.06 is there to add in the cost of sales tax.  Quantity is entered by the user in pounds, the formula converts it to grains, or is supposed to.  When I use that formula, I get weird results. When I run the script with a powder price of 29.99, quantity of 1, it gives me an output of 32.  Something is obviously not calculating correctly.

So, I changed the formula to

```
(pprice*0.06+pprice)/pquantity
```

and instead of entering 1 for the quantity, I can put in the total grains instead of pounds (7000 for 1lb of powder or 56000 for 8lbs), which is fine since it will always be one or the other.

I then ran into an issue of result precision.  The output was only to 4 decimal places on the powder.  I needed that output to go to out as far as possible.  Since a single grain of powder is incredibly small in terms of price, it seems immaterial, but will be important later when calculating per cartridge prices and especially when calculating multiples of cartridges, such as 20 rounds per "box."  The same is true for primers as they come in boxes of 1000.  I then tried adding:

```
return pcost.toPrecision(8);
```

but that did not change anything.  So after adding more fields for primers and brass and playing around, I found that the code line

```
return bcost,toPrecision(2);
```

was the culprit.  By removing the ".toPrecision" portion, everything returns out to however many decimals it actually calculates to.

On to the next step, now to have it do more math and output the cost of a single, complete round by adding the unit cost for each item together (and then round it up to 2 decimals).  Going to go try working on that now...I'll probably have more questions on this..

Here's the current working code:

```
(function () {
    function calculateUnitCost(bprice, bquantity) {
        bprice = parseFloat(bprice);
        bquantity = parseFloat(bquantity);
        bcost = (bprice*0.06+bprice)/bquantity;
        pprice = parseFloat(pprice);
        pquantity = parseFloat(pquantity);
        pcost = (pprice*0.06+pprice)/pquantity;
        prprice = parseFloat(prprice);
        prquantity = parseFloat(prquantity);
        prcost = (prprice*0.06+prprice)/prquantity;
        brprice = parseFloat(brprice);
        brquantity = parseFloat(brquantity);
        brcost = (brprice*0.06+brprice)/brquantity;
        return bcost;

    }

    var unitCost = document.getElementById("unitCost");
    if (unitCost) {
        unitCost.onsubmit = function () {
            this.bunit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.bprice.value, this.bquantity.value);
            this.punit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.pprice.value, this.pquantity.value);
            this.prunit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.prprice.value, this.prquantity.value);
            this.brunit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.brprice.value, this.brquantity.value);
            return false;
        };

    }
}());
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate both Bullet and Powder Unit cost on "Calculate Per Unit Cost button" and populate Per Unit Cost textbox for Bullet as well as Powder?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I want to press the calculate button once and have all the calculations done for each item with the answer populated in the unit box for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code if Per Unit calculation formula is same for Powder.

```js
(function () {
    function calculateUnitCost(bprice, bquantity) {
        bprice = parseFloat(bprice);
        bquantity = parseFloat(bquantity);
        bcost = (bprice*0.06+bprice)/bquantity;
        return bcost.toPrecision(2);
    
    }

    var unitCost = document.getElementById("unitCost");
    if (unitCost) {
        unitCost.onsubmit = function () {
            this.bunit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.bprice.value, this.bquantity.value);       
            this.punit.value = calculateUnitCost(this.pprice.value, this.pquantity.value);  
            return false;
        };

    }
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Unit Cost Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contain">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form">
      <h2>Load Cost Calculator</h3>

      <form id="unitCost" action="">
        <p>
          <label for="bullet">Bullet </label>
          <input id="bullet" name="bullet" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="bprice">Price </label>
          <input id="bprice" name="bprice" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="bquantity">Quantity </label>
          <input id="bquantity" name="bquantity" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="bunit">Unit Cost </label>
          <input id="bunit" name="bunit" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="powder">Powder </label>
          <input id="powder" name="powder" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="pprice">Price </label>
          <input id="pprice" name="pprice" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="pquantity">Quantity </label>
          <input id="pquantity" name="pquantity" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="punit">Unit Cost </label>
          <input id="punit" name="punit" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="subm"></label>
          <input type="submit" value="Calculate Per Unit Cost" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="rest"></label>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried that and it does not work.  The calculation on the powder item though, is a different formula too.

Comment: Disregard previous comment, it does work with more additions as well.  Didn't work when I tried it in a previous iteration...weird.

Comment: Yes you can write another function which should implement different logic and call it to calculate Powder..